# Debug jQuery code to get total of all rows (Ticket Types)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a ticket widget. There are few ticket types and further 3 ticket options to each ticket type. When a user starts inputting quantity for one ticket type, ticket options for other ticket types should be disabled. If the user erase the values or set the value back to zero, ticket options for other ticket types should again be enabled.

Total summary section should show the total quantity and total cost based on the inputs.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/CodingPupil/pen/zYbqPxw

Enabling/disabling the ticket option is working fine. But it is counting the total only for the first row ticket type. If I input the values to second or third or any other ticket type, it is not calculating the total. Can you please debug my jQuery code, so it shows the correct total for all the ticket types?

Check my codepen what I have tried so far:
https://codepen.io/CodingPupil/pen/zYbqPxw

HTML:

```
<div class="ticket-section">
    <div class="ticket-type" data-ticket-type="grandstand">
      <h3>Grandstand</h3>
      <div class="ticket-options">
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Adult:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="grandstand" data-option="adult" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Child/OAP:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="grandstand" data-option="child_oap" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Young Child:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="grandstand" data-option="young_child" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ticket-type" data-ticket-type="grandstand-side">
      <h3>Grandstand Side</h3>
      <div class="ticket-options">
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Adult:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="grandstand-side" data-option="adult" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Child/OAP:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="grandstand-side" data-option="child_oap" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Young Child:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="grandstand-side" data-option="young_child" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ticket-type" data-ticket-type="ringside-row-1">
        <h3>Ringside Row 1</h3>
        <div class="ticket-options">
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Adult:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="ringside-row-1" data-option="adult" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Child/OAP:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="ringside-row-1" data-option="child_oap" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Young Child:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="ringside-row-1" data-option="young_child" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ticket-type" data-ticket-type="ringside-row-2">
        <h3>Ringside Row 2</h3>
        <div class="ticket-options">
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Adult:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="ringside-row-2" data-option="adult" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Child/OAP:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="ringside-row-2" data-option="child_oap" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Young Child:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="ringside-row-2" data-option="young_child" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ticket-type" data-ticket-type="ringside-row-3">
        <h3>Ringside Row 3</h3>
        <div class="ticket-options">
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Adult:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="ringside-row-3" data-option="adult" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Child/OAP:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="ringside-row-3" data-option="child_oap" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-option">
            <label>Young Child:</label>
            <input type="number" class="ticket-qty" data-type="ringside-row-3" data-option="young_child" min="0" value="0">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Add additional ticket types and options as needed -->
</div>
  
<div class="ticket-summary">
    <h3>Total Summary</h3>
    <div class="total-info">
      <p>Total Tickets: <span id="total-tickets">0</span></p>
      <p>Total Cost: £<span id="total-cost">0.00</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        const ticketPrices = {
          grandstand: {
            adult: 20,
            child_oap: 15,
            young_child: 10
          },
          grandstand_side: {
            adult: 25,
            child_oap: 18,
            young_child: 12
          },
          ringside_row_1: {
            adult: 30,
            child_oap: 22,
            young_child: 15
          },
          ringside_row_2: {
            adult: 35,
            child_oap: 25,
            young_child: 18
          },
          ringside_row_3: {
            adult: 40,
            child_oap: 30,
            young_child: 20
          }
        };
    
        $('.ticket-qty').on('input', function() {
          var currentType = $(this).data('type');
          var activeQuantity = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    
          // Disable all inputs initially
          $('.ticket-qty').prop('disabled', true);
    
          // Enable inputs for the current ticket type
          $('.ticket-qty[data-type="' + currentType + '"]').prop('disabled', false);
    
          var totalTickets = 0;
          var totalCost = 0;
    
          $('.ticket-qty').each(function() {
            var ticketType = $(this).data('type');
            var ticketOption = $(this).data('option');
            var quantity = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    
            if (quantity > 0) {
              $(this).closest('.ticket-type').addClass('active');
            } else {
              $(this).closest('.ticket-type').removeClass('active');
            }
    
            if (ticketPrices[ticketType] && ticketPrices[ticketType][ticketOption]) {
              var ticketCost = ticketPrices[ticketType][ticketOption];
              totalTickets += quantity;
              totalCost += quantity * ticketCost;
            }
    
            if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
              $(this).val('0');
            }
          });
    
          // Check if all inputs of the active row are 0 to enable other rows
          if (activeQuantity === 0) {
            $('.ticket-qty').not('.ticket-qty[data-type="' + currentType + '"]').prop('disabled', false);
          }
    
          $('#total-tickets').text(totalTickets);
          $('#total-cost').text(totalCost.toFixed(2));
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a quick checked your HTML and JS code, i found out that on the "-" should use "_" instead.

`data-type="grandstand-side"`   should be   `data-type="grandstand_side"`, same to  `ringside-row-1`  should be   `ringside_row_1`

Try to avoid using  `-`  in programming variable code, practice to use  `_`   is better.

Comment: Thanks for the Guide Boyd. "_" solved the issue.